# Non-nautical term for space marines

Tags: science-fiction, spaceships, terminology

Many science fiction stories describe soldiers who perform spaceship boarding/defense or planetary invasions as "space marines." This is by analogy to modern marines who historically specialize in defending/assaulting naval vessels and amphibious combat.

Is there any term (neologism?) for this kind of soldier beyond adding "space" in front of an existing modern word?

Comment: Starship Troopers?

Comment: Hello Ben.  I regret that ["What is the best name for X?"](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6259#6259) questions are off-topic because they are entirely subjective ([primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436/idea-refinement-clarification-and-examples-of-vtc-reasons-for-new-users/6437#6437)) in nature.

Comment: One thing for sure, we KNOW if Trump gets his space force, they are not going to be called 'marines'. One branch of the US military never uses terms from another branch, Too much rivalry, Military SciFi seems intent on modeling space fleets after navies, believing that they would have a contiguous development from naval battleships into space battleships. Yet most astronaut commander/pilots came from the air force. Methinks Trump could change all of that going forward.

Comment: Referring to Naval Infantry as "Marines" is a strictly Western European notion.  Russia calls them... Naval Infantry, and Imperial Japan called them Special Naval Landing Forces.  Thus, names like Space Infantry, Astro-infantry and Special Astro Assault Forces (SAAFs) come to mind.

Comment: since space force is branched out of airforce, the assault troops will be inherit the "paratroopers" names. :)

Comment: @JBH I am asking for an existing term, or an exploration of linguistics similar to 0something0's answer. Either one would be largely objective, to the extent any answers on Worldbuilding can be objective.

Comment: There is no existing term for space marines because space marines do not exist, so it's impossible to be objective in this manner.  An exploration of linguistics is outside the scope of Stack Exchange, [which is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  I apologize, but historically we've closed all "What is the best name for X?" questions.

Comment: @JBH Plenty of science fiction terms exist for things that do not (i.e. Dyson sphere, torch drive). Not a reason to close. I disagree that linguistics are outside the scope of Worldbuilding, but I recognize that I'm unlikely to persuade you of that. Fortunately for me a couple good answers were already posted before the hold.

Comment: Ben, this is the rule developed over many years and after considerable discussion by many people based on the goals of the site and the intrinsic limitations of the Stack Exchange business model.  What you're missing is that names can be anything, they don't change *how* your world operates, and this site is focused on *how.*  Please take the time to read through our [help], which will assist you with understanding both the rules and the culture of this site.

Comment: @JBH Terminology shapes culture and beliefs, and has a huge impact both in the real world and in fictional worlds. For me, language is at the absolute heart of building a world. This topic is narrow enough to have concrete answers ("here's a Russian word for it", "here are 3 examples from fiction", "there is no widely accepted term for that"), but broad enough to be useful for many science fiction world builders. There's no need to insult me by describing my disagreement as a lack of understanding.

Comment: I [recently tried to get a "technobabble" tag](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6516) because your point is well taken, but it doesn't change the fact that this site focuses on the rules, not the nomenclature.  The poposal was shot down.  Such is life.

Comment: @JBH I think the _technobabble_ tag is unrelated to my question. It's more in line with the _terminology_ tag, which has several open questions similar to mine.

Comment: Regrettably, no.  17 questions in the site's history is unremarkable.  4 have been closed (almost 25%).  And look at how those quesitons are being asked: what existing unit of measure for X?  What would the Greeks call X (where X is within the cultural climate of the Greeks), Is X a good word for Y?  There's a couple that should be closed and several more where [tag:terminology] is inappropriate for the question.  My point is, most of those open questions are narrow and objective, where "What is the best name for X?" questions are broad and subjective.

Comment: You might want to read through [this meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/why-was-my-question-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based/4311#4311)

Comment: @JBH I'd draw a distinction between terminology (what I'm asking about) and proper nouns (a location name, as described in the meta post). In addition, there are clearly wrong answers to my question: I voted one the answers down for failing to answer my question. I would argue that the linked meta topic supports my question being valid, or at least doesn't argue for it to be closed.

Comment: Might be a good addition to the ongoing discussion to bring the matter up in Meta.  We have a theoretical pro (that last link) and a theoretical con (the technobabble link).  It might get your question reopened.

Answer (score 10):

**Use Portmanteaus**

*War Dogs* by Greg Bear uses the term Skyrines, a portmanteau of "sky" and "marine". If you don't like the use of the term "sky", you could substitute it for another term like say, "cosmo", to get "Cosmorine."

Other examples may include: 
astroldier - combining Astro and Soldier. A bit hard on your tongues though, decreasing efficiency in a military setting.

Plasfo - PLanetary ASsault FOrce. This one is a bit more heavy on stereotypical military terminology, but gets the job done.

**Look Into Linguistic Roots**

The term "marine" is derived from French (French "marine", from Latin "marinus", derived from "mare"). We could do the same but with the term "space". In French, the term for space is "espace" according to Google Translate, so space marines could potentially be called "espatiers" (pronounced "espaciers" as in "spatial").

(I got the above example from http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/astromilitary.php#terminology)

But this isn't the 1800s and presumably not everyone speaks a Latin-derived language. So you could potentially play around with linguistics and lore to create your terminology. For instance, I could have a world where there is a second space race and China comes out on top, and have terminologies be based on Chinese.

But regardless of language, we need to consider what would be practical. In a military setting, communication needs to be short and precise, and easy to say, so we should decrease the number of syllables while keeping the meaning clear. If you want to stick to English and keep it linguistically reasonable, I say you should get common phrases like in the other answers and play around with them (see above section).

Comment: Espatiers sounds pretty good. I like your idea.

Answer (score 4):

In the context of your world, if the vast majority of engagements are fought ship-to-ship, or ship-to-station, they could simply be "soldiers" or "troopers" without any particular need for a prefix.

Essentially these types of actions have become so commonplace that doesn't make sense to draw attention to it  - it's just a part of an ordinary soldiers job.

Other ideas:

- Voidnaut
- Shocktrooper

@Clay Deitas mentioned referring to them like modern special forces, e.g. "Green Beret", which I think is a good idea

Answer (score 4):

Tough call.

I tend to refer to people who specialize in fighting within ships as "Boarding soldier", but that doesn't seem like what your talking about.

I guess "Exo-trooper" could work, referring to combatants who operate outside atmospheres.

Personally, I'd be tempted to refer to these guys as "Rocketeers", but that's technically already in use. Plus it might be a bit too retro-sounding.

If I was allowed to get fancy, I'd claim that Russians established the first military bases and space-specialized soldiers. The russian weapons program to arm these soilders was designated **operatsiya: kosmicheskiy rytsar'** (operation: space knight), so the term for any null-gravity soilder became "Raystar."

The most generic-sounding one would probably be "Spacer", which I kind of like because it sounds equal parts insulting, pessimistic, and threatening.

I think that's all I got in my arsenal at the moment, but I might edit more in later.

Wait, you could call these guys "Kents" after the secret identity of superman. Might be a fun way of poking fun at their egos, you know?

Edit: 30-secs would be a fun nickname at least. That's about how long humans can survive in a hard vacuum.

Comment: As much as I liked Raystars, Kents was an absolutely hilarious answer.

Comment: Combining a couple of ideas here - Astrooper? Although, I know where that'll be taken in every schoolyard on the planet...

Comment: Exotroopers is a pretty good neologism, and I imagine soldiers would enjoy abbreviating it ETs.

Comment: @Ben Oh dang, I wish I thought of that. Not only is a natural abbreviation, it's also on theme.

Answer (score 3):

- [Dragoons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragoon)
- [Hussars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hussar) (also, [Winged Hussars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_hussars), if you like extra adjectives)
- [Grenadiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenadiers_%C3%A0_Cheval_de_la_Garde_Imp%C3%A9riale)
- [[Commander-in-Chief Title] Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praetorian_Guard)
- [[Ethnic Group Name] Scouts/Rifles/Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5th_Gorkha_Rifles_(Frontier_Force))
- [Rangers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Army_Rangers) ([alternately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranger_(Middle-earth)))
- [Sturmtruppen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormtrooper) ([alternately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormtrooper_(Star_Wars)))
- [Arditi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arditi)
- [Verloren Hoop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forlorn_hope)
- [Askari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Askari)
- [Companions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_cavalry)
- [Immortals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortals_(Achaemenid_Empire)) (works better for robots)

Comment: Downvoted because this is a list of modern or historical soldier names which have nothing to do with space or the combat role I described.

Answer (score 1):

I always liked the idea of space being referred to as the Abyss.  You could call the more hardened soldiers "Abyssers" or something along those lines.

A more technical term would have to use "Astro" somehow, but Astrosoldiers sounds lame.

Answer (score 0):

Cosmonauts.

Astrotroopers.

Star Soldiers.

Or any feature given to the standard space soldier, like the name Green Barrett.

Comment: Cosmonaut is a nautical name, so that's out.